# Lifetime of local variables inside an Object Constructor Function

Tags: javascript

In this example, taken from the W3Schools JS Tutorial, how is it possible for the variable `n` to still be used in the `next` function ?

```
// Home Made Iterable
function myNumbers() {
  let n = 0;
  return {
    next: function() {
      n += 10;
      return {value:n, done:false};
    }
  };
}

// Create Iterable
const n = myNumbers();
n.next(); // Returns 10
n.next(); // Returns 20
n.next(); // Returns 30
```

I'm coming from a C/C++ background and the lifetime of this variable makes no sense to me. It seems to behave like a global static variable but it should have been deleted when exiting `myNumbers()`, especially when declared with the `let` keyword. How can, then, the `next` method uses it without raising a `ReferenceError` and keeping its value updated ?

Comment: JavaScript has *closures*.

Comment: it's more like all variables are `std::shared_ptr<any>`. So you can capture it no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Because of a closure feature of the JavaScript, keep the variable accessible even if the containing function died, whenever there is a child function still need to access it.

For more resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures